# Power series expansion for a circulant matrix

Tags: matrices, power-series, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus, circulant-matrices

Let $A$ the block matrix given by the blocks:
$$\tilde{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&-\mu&0&...&0&-\mu\\
-\mu&1&-\mu&...&0&0\\
0&-\mu&1&...&0&0\\
...&...&...&...&...\\
0&0&0&...&1&-\mu\\
-\mu&0&0&...&-\mu&1
\end{pmatrix}\quad\quad A^*=\mathbf{diag}(-\mu,-\mu,...,-\mu) $$
where $\mu<1$.

So $$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{A}&A^*&0&...&0&A^*\\
A^*&\tilde{A}&A^*&0&...&0\\
0&A^*&\tilde{A}&...&...&0\\
...&...&...&...&...&...\\
A^*&0&...&0&A^*&\tilde{A}
\end{pmatrix} $$
Am I allowed to expand in power series this matrix with something like
$$A^{1/4}=\mathbb{I}+\sum_{k\geq 1} \binom{1/4}{k}(-1)^k(\mu T)^k$$
where $T=\frac{1}{\mu}(\mathbb{I}-A)$? Any references where can I study these kind of expansion?

Comment: Are you acquainted with the diagonalization of circulant matrices?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RodrigodeAzevedo. A litlle bit, however my reference for circulant matrices is "Circulant Matrices" by Philip J.Davis. Can you help me?

Comment: I usually use Gray's [Toeplitz and Circulant Matrices](https://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.html).

Comment: Ok, I will check it. Nothing arises about my question?

Comment: Why don't you define $A^{\frac14}$ that way, compute it via diagonalization and then take its 4th power to see if you get back to $A$?