# Spectral radius of a block circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Let $A$ the block matrix given by the blocks:
$$\tilde{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&-\mu&0&...&0&-\mu\\
-\mu&0&-\mu&...&0&0\\
0&-\mu&0&...&0&0\\
...&...&...&...&...\\
0&0&0&...&0&-\mu\\
-\mu&0&0&...&-\mu&
\end{pmatrix}\quad\quad A^*=\mathbf{diag}(-\mu,-\mu,...,-\mu) $$
So $$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{A}&A^*&0&...&0&A^*\\
A^*&\tilde{A}&A^*&0&...&0\\
0&A^*&\tilde{A}&...&...&0\\
...&...&...&...&...&...\\
A^*&0&...&0&A^*&\tilde{A}
\end{pmatrix} $$
Does anyone know some trick to calculate spectral radius of $A$? Maybe I can use the matrix norm defined by $||A||_1 = \max_{1\le j \le n} \sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}|$

Comment: This is not quite a circulant matrix, but it is block-circulant. You can look up eigenvalues of block circulant matrices for tips (as a bonus, each block is circulant as well).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4026661/339790

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Gerschgorin disc theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), $\rho(A)\le4|\mu|$. Since $Ae=-4\mu e$ (where $e$ is the vector of ones), we conclude that $\rho(A)=4|\mu|$.

Actually we can obtain all eigenvalues of $A$ explicitly. Let $S_r$ be the real symmetric $r\times r$ matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&1&0&\cdots&0&1\\
1&0&1&\ddots&\vdots&0\\
0&1&\ddots&\ddots&0&\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
0&\cdots&0&\ddots&0&1\\
1&0&\cdots&0&1&0}.
$$
This matrix is circulant and its eigenvalues admit an explicit formula:
$$
\lambda_k^{(r)}=e^{2\pi ik/r}+e^{2\pi ik(r-1)/r}=2\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{r}\right),\ k=0,1,\ldots,r-1.
$$
Now suppose that $\tilde{A}$ (or $A^\ast$) has $m$ rows and $A$ has $n$ block rows.
Then $A=-\mu(I_n\otimes S_m+S_n\otimes I_m)$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $A$ are  given by
$$
-\mu(\lambda_k^{(m)}+\lambda_l^{(n)})
=-2\mu\left(\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{m}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2l\pi}{n}\right)\right)
$$
where $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}$ and $l\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Comment: Wow, really thank you. I've never seen the Gerschgorin disc theorem, it seems to be very useful and versed. My original problem was showing that I can expand $(\mathbf{I}+ A)^{1/4}$ in power series, so I needed $||A||<1$. Do you think that $\mu<1/4$ it's enough to this purpose?

Comment: @GiovanniFebbraro Yes, it's enough. $\mu<\frac14\ \Rightarrow\|A\|_2=\rho(A)<1$ and hence the binomial series of $(I+A)^{1/4}$ converges absolutely.